# How to connect google cloud sql's Postgres database to django application

Tags: google-cloud-sql

can anybody explain about connecting gcp cloud sql's postgres database to django application. I tried to connecting using the endpoint they provided,but its not working.

Comment: You should have a look at the doc here https://cloud.google.com/python/django/. It's quite well explained, you just need to choose the environment you want to deploy to.

Answer (score 0):

Are you having troubles when trying to connect to your Cloud SQL instance (PostgreSQL) using Django in Google Cloud Platform?

In order to help, I would like to know which documentation you were following in order to test your application.

Are you using App Engine Flexible or Standard Environment? Or are you using another Cloud Platform product/service?

Is this documentation [1] you were using? For example, this doc explains how to connect to Cloud SQL (PostgreSQL) in the App Engine Flexible environment with Django.

If you could share further details on this would be great, such as the sample you used.

Are you receiving any error/warning messages? Which (if any)?
Are you using the Cloud SDK or your Cloud Console to deploy?
Have you tried deploying on your local environment with success?

Take into account the following documentation in order to learn further information about Getting Started with Django [2].

Thank you.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment

[2] https://cloud.google.com/python/django/